# MySQL syntax error event Scheduler

Tags: mysql

What's is wrong?
I Succeeded in creating the Scheduled EVENT.
It doesn't work and something is wrong near 'END' syntax, MySQL says...

```
 DELIMITER ||
CREATE
EVENT ScheduledCalls
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS NOW()
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
    -- insert if less than 60 minutes
    INSERT INTO tblcalls(
        DateTimeReceived, ClientID, CorpName, StartDay,
        StartTime, FromInfo, FromContact, FromPhone, ToInfo,
        ToContact, ToPhone, Memo,Service, StrService, AR, Status)
    SELECT
        DateTimeReceived, ClientID, CorpName, StartDay,
        StartTime, FromInfo, FromContact, FromPhone, ToInfo,
        ToContact, ToPhone, Memo, Service, StrService, AR, Status
    FROM 
        tblscheduledcalls
    WHERE
        TIMEDIFF(StartDateTime, NOW()) < "00:60:00";

    -- delete inserted record(s) from tblcalls
    DELETE FROM tblscheduledcalls
    WHERE
        TIMEDIFF(StartDateTime, NOW()) < "00:60:00";
END ||
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
EVENT ScheduledCalls
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS NOW()
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
    -- insert if less than 60 minutes
    INSERT INTO tblscheduledcalls(
        DateTimeReceived, ClientID, CorpName, StartDay,
        StartTime, FromInfo, FromContact, FromPhone, ToInfo,
        ToContact, ToPhone, Memo,Service, StrService, AR, Status)
    SELECT
        DateTimeReceived, ClientID, CorpName, StartDay,
        StartTime, FromInfo, FromContact, FromPhone, ToInfo,
        ToContact, ToPhone, Memo, Service, StrService, AR, Status
    FROM 
        tblcalls
    WHERE
        TIMEDIFF(StartDateTime, NOW()) < "00:60:00";

    -- delete inserted record(s) from tblcalls
    DELETE FROM tblscheduledcalls
    WHERE
        TIMEDIFF(StartDateTime, NOW()) < "00:60:00";
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That worked, I realize that my syntax was also correct. Another thing is that I was wrong in my INSERT TO about tables, so I edited it. The event doesn't still to work though... When opening created event, there's a red X on the last line still saying something is wrong (near END).